# What story features the day electricity vanished?

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

I think this short story was written in 50's or 60's.   The premise is that all of a sudden, all forms of electricity stopped working, and people had to revert to a simpler way of life.

Comment: In the same vein (but not a match as it's longer and more recent) is S.M. Stirling's [Emberverse series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emberverse_series)

Comment: Possible dupe; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60556/book-where-all-electricity-stopped-working/60655#60655

Comment: I take it you are after a book - and not "The Day The Earth Stood Still"?

Answer (score 10):

It could be **The Waveries**, from Fredric Brown (1945). In the story, true or not, the waves have the effect of interfering with electricity.

> "The Waveries" describes the story of an invasion of Earth by beings not quite organic, drawn to the planet through space by radio and other transmissions that had drifted through space. Caught up in the "scent" the wave-like beings surround the Earth and begin siphoning off any electricity generated anywhere on the planet, effectively de-industrializing the earth overnight. And the story takes us just far enough ahead to see that humanity adapts and rebuilds society as best they can.

The protagonist of the story is a radio ad writer. Aliens who can live in wave forms come to Earth and make use of any wave communications impossible. People go back to a simpler way of life, and it seems that most of them are happier (the ride horses or carriages, they ride bikes and become healthier, play music themselves instead of listen to the one in the radio, they socialize more, because they have these bands, they don't stay at home *glued* to the radio, etc...).

Comment: "But damn it, he *missed* the lightning"" Such a good story, I have  acopy myself :)

Comment: I've been trying to rediscover this title since 1985.